# playframework 2.2.1 ebean how to use java refection update entity

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I am new to Play framework & ebean
And want make a common util function to update my Model's instance
so I used following code:

```
private static void updateEntity(Class cls, Long id, ObjectNode data){
    Object instance = Ebean.find(cls,id);

    for (Field field :cls.getFields()){
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        if (!fieldName.equals("id")){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                field.set(instance, data.get(fieldName).toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    try {
      //not work  
      cls.getMethod("save").invoke(instance);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //not work too
    //Ebean.save(instance);

}
```

I call it by using:

```
    Long id = 1L;
    Class cls = MyEntity.class;
    ObjectNode data = Json.newObject();
    data.put("name","Hello world");
    data.put("id",1L);
    updateEntity(cls,id,data);
```

MyEntity is a nomarl entity class for model which contains id and name
So , How do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void updateEntity(Class cls, Long id, ObjectNode data){

User user = Ebean.find(cls,id);     // For example, consider Ebean returns 'User' object. You can mention your Model here.

try{
    user.getClass().getDeclaredField("id").set(user, data.get("id").toString());
}
catch(NoSuchFieldException exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();    // If no field is found in the name of `id`.
}   
catch(NullPointerException exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();    // If field name is null
}   
catch(Exception exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
}   

user.save();
}
```

Comment: you don't understand my means:I want dynamic update all my models,like User class, Product class and so on.So can't use the a specific Class ,mybe the Model class is fine;Also I think the key in  the set method,I make break point in it and it changes the object's property ,but after this function finished,the data in database not changes

Comment: I think the java reflection method not work on Ebean ORM,Maybe Ebean do something else that we don't know to change the value for database